# i'm getting NaN as a result beside a number in the last function

Tags: javascript, arrays, function, object, nan

```
var john  = {
name: 'John Smith',
bills: [124,48,268,180,42],
tips : [],
final: [],
calcTips: function(){
    for(i = 0; i < this.bills.length;i++){
        if(this.bills[i] < 50){
            this.tips[i] = this.bills[i] * 0.2;
            this.final[i] = this.bills[i] + this.tips[i];
        } else if(this.bills[i] >= 50 && this.bills[i] <= 200){
            this.tips[i] = this.bills[i] * 0.15;
            this.final[i] = this.bills[i] + this.tips[i];
        } else{
            this.tips[i] = this.bills[i] * 0.1;
            this.final[i] = this.bills[i] + this.tips[i];
        }
    }
}
```

};

```
var mark  = {
name: 'Mark Smith',
bills: [77,375,110,45],
tips : [],
final: [],
calcTips: function(){
    for(i = 0; i < this.bills.length;i++){
        if(this.bills[i] < 100){
            this.tips[i] = this.bills[i] * 0.2;
            this.final[i] = this.bills[i] + this.tips[i];
        } else if(this.bills[i] >= 100 && this.bills[i] <= 300){
            this.tips[i] = this.bills[i] * 0.1;
            this.final[i] = this.bills[i] + this.tips[i];
        } else{
            this.tips[i] = this.bills[i] * 0.25;
            this.final[i] = this.bills[i] + this.tips[i];
        }
    }
}
```

};

```
function calcAverage(tips){
var sum = 0;
for(i = 0; i < tips.length ; i++){
    sum = tips[i] + sum;
}
return sum / tips.length;
```

}

```
mark.Average = calcAverage(mark.tips);
john.Average = calcAverage(john.tips);
mark.calcTips();
john.calcTips();
console.log(john);
console.log(mark);
```

the functin calcAverage returns NaN beisde the average number.
i coded it so it will loop the tips array and add to the sum variable the tips plus the sum.
could someome please explain the problem?

Comment: When `tips.length == 0`, you'd get `0 / 0` which is indeed `NaN`.

Answer (score 0):

You're calling `calcAverage` **before** calling `calcTips`, so the arrays are empty. `calcAverage` ends with `return sum / tips.length`. Since `sum` is `0` and `tips.length` is `0`, that's `NaN` (in JavaScript, `0/0` is `NaN` since JavaScript uses IEEE 754 double-precision floating point, which specifies that behavior).

To fix it:

1. Don't divide `sum` when `tips.length` is `0`, and
2. Calculate the tips before calculating the average.

Comment: Your last statement is wrong. Try `console.log(1.0 / 0);`. And it's also wrong in C/C++ BTW, and probably in other languages where floating-point format supports `+inf` and `-inf`.

Comment: thanks a lot. can't beilieve I did this kind of mistake :P

Comment: Even `1 / 0` doesn't return `NaN` (though this would not be the case in typed languages).

Comment: `console.log(typeof (50 / 0)); // -> number` Infinity is a number

Comment: @goodvibration - Thanks! Fixed it. That's what I get for posting quickly and heading off to dinner. It's `0 / `0` (which the OP was doing) that results in `NaN`. `x / 0` where `x` is anything but `NaN` or `0` results in `Infinity` or `-Infinity`. Note that this doesn't have anything to do with JavaScript being loosely typed; `NaN`, `Infinity`, etc. are all of the `number` type (IEEE-754 double-precision floating point). This is all per the IEEE 754-2019 specification.

Comment: It actually does have to do with Javascript being loosely-typed. Well, kinda loosely-typed, as `Number` is essentially a floating-point type, and there is no distinguish between this type and (one or more) integer types. Hence in contrast with strongly-typed languages, `1` and `1.0` are regarded as the same type. Hence in contrast with such languages, in Javascript `1 / 0 == NaN`.

Comment: BTW, I believe that "anything but `NaN` or `0` results in `Infinity` or `-Infinity`" is also wrong. Try `1 / undefined` and `1 / "x"`. The correct statement would be "**everything but** `x / 0` results with `NaN`, where `x` is an expression which evaluates to a non-zero number or to a string representing a non-zero number".

Comment: @goodvibration - I'm afraid you're mistaken about your loosely-typed claim. Again, `NaN` is a `number` (despite it being short for "not a number" :-) ). The type of the result of `/` is **always** `number` ([spec](https://tc39.es/ecma262/#sec-numeric-types-number-divide)), **exactly** like `double / double` is always `double` in Java (which is strongly-typed). This behavior is the same in JavaScript (loosely typed) and Java (strongly typed; [see it here](https://ideone.com/5ifNZV)), it has nothing to do with JavaScript being loosely typed, it has to do with the IEEE-754 specification.

Comment: @goodvibration - I meant "any *number* other than `NaN` or `0`", which seems clear to me from context, but whatever.

Comment: Like I said - "kinda loosely-typed", by which I meant that there is no distinguish between floating-point and integer. So we're technically arguing about the exact definition of loosely-typed I suppose.

Comment: @goodvibration - JavaScript doesn't do integer division with `number`s, see the specification link above (which literally says that). (It does integer division with BigInts, of course.)

Comment: No distinguish between the types of `1` and `1.0`. Hence `1 / 0 == Infinity`, where in C/C++/Java, this would throw a division-by-zero exception. The different behavior is due to the fact that the latter languages DO distinguish these two types, hence my point in saying that Javascript is "more loosely-typed" than these languages.

Comment: @goodvibration - At no point did I suggest that JavaScript isn't loosely typed. I said the result of `0 / 0` being `NaN` has nothing to do with JavaScript being loosely typed. If you want to draw a distinction with C++ or Java, the distinction is that in JavaScript, a numeric literal with no type suffix always defines a `number` (double), whereas in (say) Java it defines an `int` if it doesn't have a `.` in it or a `double` if it does. I'm done with this. Have a good one.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I can see, the average tip is calculated before the tips actually exist. If you move the calculation of the tips above, it should work fine:

```
mark.calcTips();
john.calcTips();
mark.Average = calcAverage(mark.tips);
john.Average = calcAverage(john.tips);
console.log(john);
console.log(mark);
```

Answer (score 0):

try calling these functions

`mark.calcTips(); john.calcTips();`

before

```
mark.Average = calcAverage(mark.tips);
john.Average = calcAverage(john.tips);
```

because tips are empty array when you call calcAverage() function

code should be

```
mark.calcTips();
john.calcTips(); 
mark.Average = calcAverage(mark.tips);
john.Average = calcAverage(john.tips);
```

Answer (score 0):

Problem revolves around "[this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this)" binding when you call that function. you can see `calcTips` had been called using [apply()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/apply), however I'd only extracted the function for demonstration purpose; this code still can be improved  but didn't change it much so you can see what happens;

Check the code snippet:

```js
var john = {
  name: "John Smith",
  bills: [124, 48, 268, 180, 42],
  tips: [],
  final: []
};

var mark = {
  name: "Mark Smith",
  bills: [77, 375, 110, 45],
  tips: [],
  final: []
};

function calcTips() {
  for (let i = 0; i < this.bills.length; i++) {
    if (this.bills[i] < 100) {
      this.tips[i] = this.bills[i] * 0.2;
      this.final[i] = this.bills[i] + this.tips[i];
    } else if (this.bills[i] >= 100 && this.bills[i] <= 300) {
      this.tips[i] = this.bills[i] * 0.1;
      this.final[i] = this.bills[i] + this.tips[i];
    } else {
      this.tips[i] = this.bills[i] * 0.25;
      this.final[i] = this.bills[i] + this.tips[i];
    }
  }
}

function calcAverage(tips) {
  var sum = 0;
  for (i = 0; i < tips.length; i++) {
    sum = tips[i] + sum;
  }
  return sum / tips.length;
}

//calling calcTips with "this" refers to mark 
calcTips.apply(mark);

//calling calcTips with "this" refers to john 
calcTips.apply(john);

mark.Average = calcAverage(mark.tips);
john.Average = calcAverage(john.tips);
console.log(john);
console.log(mark);
```